# Does drawing icons have better performance than using an image in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

I am working with a WPF application and I came from web development background where I used to use images to show all kind of icons. But in this wpf project I found my senior developer draws them using wpf shapes.

So, it occurred to me is there a well known reason to do that? I mean does it enhance the performance somehow if I draw the icons instead of using images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`So, it occurred to me is there a well known reason to do that?`

WPF has vector graphics. They stretch infinitely without losing resolution / quality.

In contrast, bitmaps (such as PNG or JPG) have a specific pixel resolution and they look bad when enlarged too much.

In terms of performance, displaying a bitmap is much cheaper than drawing a vector icon.

Comment: But to OP's original questions, is there any noticeable improvement in the performance of the application, or is it purely for aesthetic purposes?